# How to create animation for imgProgress.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using imgProgress.js plugin to display progress bar with centre circular image.

## what i have tried

**script**

```
 var myProgress = jqueryObj("#demo1").imgProgress(
        {
            img_url: "/Content/Images/BestManager/driver15.jpg",
            size: 180,
            backgroundColor: '#f3f7f2',
            foregroundColor: '#ff0505',
            animation:true,

            percent: 23
        }
    );
```

**html**

```
<div id="demo1" class="bgimg"></div><br />
```

## What i need

i need animation for that progress bar like continuously loading or Animated stripes.

Comment: Typically GIFs are used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that plug in you need to add some style manually.

```
  .imgProgress-svg{
        animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
    }
    @@keyframes rotate {
   from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution!thank you